# How to call a function when MKPointAnnotation is pressed in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have been trying everything to get a annotation to call a function in swift. I don't know if I am doing something wrong but it just won't work.
I've tried testing my project on a real iphone but nothing happend as well.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

//Map

@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

let manager = CLLocationManager()

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
    let location = locations[0]

    let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "coffee"

    // Set the region to an associated map view's region
    request.region = map.region

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
    search.start { response, error in
        guard let response = response else {
            print("There was an error searching for: \(String(describing: request.naturalLanguageQuery)) error: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        for item in response.mapItems
        {
            print("URL=\(String(describing: item.url ?? nil))")
            print("Name=\(String(describing: item.name ?? nil))")
            print("Phone Number\(String(describing: item.phoneNumber ?? nil))")


            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate
            annotation.title = item.name
            self.map.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }
    self.map.showsUserLocation = true
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func callThisFunction() {
    print("The function has been called.")
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
    callThisFunction()
}
```

I've looked at many articles about how to do this, but I can't quite pull it off. Any heads up on my code would be great, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
map.delegate = self
```

to your viewDidLoad()

Oh, and Xcode tells me, that

> Instance method 'mapView(mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'mapView(_:didSelect:)' of protocol 'MKMapViewDelegate'

You should fix that too, using the "Fix" button.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I have been trying to get this to work for hours!!